# Alternative of '$lookup' for MongoDB 2.4?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

By using '$lookup' and '$unwind' pair in pipeline stage of mongodb 2.x throwing error. As undefined pipeline stage '$lookup'

Is there any similar function/keyword of '$lookup' which can be used for previous mongodb versions?

Answer (score 0):

No, $lookup was a new feature in MongoDB 3.2. No previous feature fulfilled this need. I recommend upgrading MongoDB.